# Laravel 5.2 generate random number and save to database

Tags: php, laravel, random, numbers

I am new to Laravel and I am creating a client table where i have different fields, but also, i have a field called client_number which i want to generate random numbers in laravel and save them to that specific column without a duplicate as well.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks alot

Comment: I want something similar to godaddys customer number

Comment: Add unique index then `random_int` or `mt_rand`. Also add a condition while inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***str_rand() or rand()*** predefined functions for get Random Number and check it in DB

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

 //Generate Random Number
 do{
   $randomString = str_random(2).rand().str_random(2);
   $rand =  "CLI_".$randomString;
 }while(!empty(clients ::where('client_number',$rand)->first()));

//Insert Query
 $Clients = new clients ;
 $Clients ->name = $request->name;
 $Clients ->client_number = $rand;
 $Clients ->save();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Place these three methods into your controller where you are going to handle client registration. In store method you can add more client parameters. You will need to import Client Model in your controller can be done by writing `use App\Client;` and also request handler.

In second method I am checking in table if client number exist or not.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
        {

            $client = new Client;

        $client->name = $request->name;
        $client->client_name = $this->getClientNumber();
        $client->save();
    }


      public function getClientNumber(){
         do{
             $rand = $this->generateRandomString(6);
          }while(!empty(Client::where('client_number',$rand)->first()));
           return $rand;
        }



    public function generateRandomString($length) {
        $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
     }
```